# How to get selected from jmultiselect2side in yii and display in a new page

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm new to yii and I don't understand the extensions much
but I used this extension called jmultiselect2side because I'm trying to make a site where users could reserve stuff like apparatuses in the lab

Anyway, I need a code that would get the Selected Items and then display them in another page for viewing purposes

I haven't put anything in the controller but the name of my controller and model is Apparatus

Here is my view:

```
    <?php
    $model= Apparatus::model()->findByAttributes(array('ApparatusCode'=>'1'));
    // complete user list to be shown at multiselect order by ApparatusCode
    $Apparatus= Apparatus::model()->findAll(
             array('order' => 'ApparatusCode'));
    ?>
   <center>
    <?php
             $this-  >widget('application.extensions.jmultiselect2side.Jmultiselect2side',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'attribute'=>'ApparatusName', //selected items
                'labelsx'=>'Available',
                'labeldx'=>'Selected',
                'moveOptions'=>false,
                'autoSort'=>'true',
                'search'=>'Search:',
              'list'=>CHtml::listData(             // available items
                   $Apparatus,
                   'ApparatusCode',
                   'ApparatusName'),

         ));
     ?>
```

please help as soon as possible :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put all above elements in a form. Set action for the form. Submit the form then the action in which you are handling this submit request, you can write there

```
if(isset($_POST))
{
foreach($_POST['Apparatus']['ApparatusName'] as $name)
{
 do what ever you want
}
}
```

`$name` will represent the each selected item